# looking way back in the past data within pine not working anymore

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Previously I  was able to test couple years of backtest data in pine (even if it was not visble on chart) through the following code

```
                        // === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
fromMonth = input.int(defval = 08,    title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)

fromDay   = input.int(defval = 01,    title = "From Day",  minval = 1, maxval = 31)

fromYear  = input.int(defval = 2020, title = "From Year", minval = 1970)

thruMonth = input.int(defval = 06,    title = "Thru Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)

thruDay   = input.int(defval = 28,    title = "Thru Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)

thruYear  = input.int(defval = 2112, title = "Thru Year", minval = 1970)


                        // === INPUT SHOW PLOT ===
showDate  = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range")

                        // === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 13, 00)        // backtest start window

finish    = timestamp(thruYear, thruMonth, thruDay, 20, 00)        // backtest finish window

window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false       // create function "within window of time"


strategy.entry(...when = window())

/////////////////////////////////
```

Now it is not working. i am trying to test something in 5min tf and it is only showing me from march 8th 2023. How can I look further back? is it that TV is not allowing it so that only premium users can use new "deep backtesting" option?

Answer (score 0):

Deep backtesting is only available for Premium subscribers. You can compare different plans from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/gopro/#compare).

[image]